# How to enable ssl on old VB.net app with IIS 7?

Tags: vb.net, ssl, iis

I have a `VB.net app` developed before 2010 with `visual web developer express 2008`. The app is running with IIS 7 (.NET framework 2.0) on MS `server 2008`.   Without changing code in vb.net app, is there a way I can enable `ssl` with only configuration of IIS7? I can add `https` to IIS and generate my CA. I don't have `visual studio` and can not use VS for `ssl`.

Comment: Unless your app actually has code that specifies links or something with specifically http hard coded into it, binding the cert to the website in IIS for port 443 should be all you need to do.  IIS stands between your app and the world to handle the SSL connection.  If you remove the port 80 binding, any http requests will fail and only https will pass. That breakage may or may not be desirable in your  individual case.

Comment: This should be ideal if IIS can handle all about ssl. No, I don't recall any hard code about http in the app. Http 80 traffic needs to be redirected to port 443 for https.